# send notification from objectivec and receive in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Trying to send notification from objective c and receive in swift. I see no error from sender or receiver and function is not called in target view controller

ViewController 1: Objective c

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"notifyme"
     object:self
     userInfo:self.profile];
```

ViewController 2: swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("view did load")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "receiveNotification:", name: "notifyme", object: nil)

}

func receiveNotification(ns: NSNotification){
    print("Received Notification")

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by sending from obj c and reseved on swift lol

Comment: I meant sending notification from objective c code and trying to receive it from swift code.sorry for the typo. please check the partial code pasted. Let me know if any further information is required. Appreciate your quick response

Comment: Add @objc annotation above `receiveNotification` if you had any issues. Otherwise your code look fine.

Comment: I believe I tried adding @objc still its not being called

Comment: When do you send the notification ? Are both view controller initialized when ViewController 1 sends notification ?

Comment: My understanding is yes if the viewDidLoad() of target/second container is called. I am new to swift "view controller initialized?"

Answer (score 3):

In Swift3, I Solved this problem

Send OC

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:"You NotificationName" object:nil];
```

Receive Swift 3

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "You NotificationName"), object: nil)
}
func handleNotification() -> Void {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps:

First Of all add this in your ViewController.swift which is your first view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "receiveNotification:", name: "notifyme", object: nil)
}

func receiveNotification(ns: NSNotification){
    print("Received Notification")
}
```

After that add a new class in Obj-c and don't forget to create bridging header for that class.

In bridging header file add import your SecondViewController this way:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
```

And in your `SecondViewController.m` add this code when you go back to your swift viewController.

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"notifyme"
     object:nil
     userInfo:nil];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

For more Info check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=41014427334389417066) sample project.

**Update:**

If first controller is objective c and second/target controller is swift.

**FirstViewController.m**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
                                                 name:@"TestNotification"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
}
@end
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
@IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("TestNotification", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
```

**[Sample code](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=19569362046152469112)**

Comment: Little confused. My first controller is objective c and second/target controller is swift. Still the suggestion is applicable

Comment: View Controller 1: Objcdetailed                                                if (self.profile)
    {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"loginViewDidFinish"
         object:self
         userInfo:self.profile];
    }


    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];

    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. First controller is the objective c which is the sender of the notification. Receiver controller is swift. Your sample codes are very helpful though

Comment: can you share any sample project?

Comment: just to update on the use case I have 3 view controllers as follows                1. View Controller Swift, 2. View Controller Objc (notification sender), 3. View Controller Swift (notification receiver)

Comment: You notification is not working because your third view is not created when you call the notification.

Comment: Can you help me understand "view not created?" and how it can be done.